# Fragmentactivity onbackpress

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onkeydown, onbackpressed

I'm extending `FragmentActivity` and overriding `onBackPress` to do nothing except putting in log code to see back button touched.

The problem is when I touch a back button the overriding of `onBackPress`, not all touches get detected but it affects the app.

1. I have a loading indicator it's gone after I touch the back button. In the console log, I do not see back button press logged.
2. I touch the back button again the dialog box under the loading indicator. In the console log, I also do not see back button press logged.
3. Back button touched again, this time I can see it in the log but it goes back to the previous fragment.

All of this shouldn't happen because I had overridden the `onBackPressed` function to only put in logs.

I have also tried overriding `onKeyDown` and `dispatchKeyEvent` to detect `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` but the #1 and #2 above also cannot be detected in `onKeyDown` and `dispatchKeyEvent`.

Anything else I can try to stop back button to affect my app?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super.onBackPressed` if you want to override

Comment: I did a search on the project cannot find super.onBackPressed. Any other suggestions?